# Good tutorial available for XCode with VST3?

Tags: xcode, vst

I am completely new to both the world of XCode and VST.
Every tutorial I find deals with VST2.4 or earlier, when I really want to rork with VST3.
I also currently have XCode 3.2.1 which doesn't have the Carbon framework which all other tutorials require.

Any ideas or documentation I can refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Carbon framework, when you install Xcode it gives you the option of also installing the 10.4 SDK which I think you may need.  Note that Carbon is deprecated for 64-bit, but you can still build 32-bit targets with it.

Answer (score 0):

The VST3 SDK from Steinberg includes XCode project files in the "public.sdk/samples/vst/mac" folder.  You should be able to open that up and take a look at how it is set up.  I can't confirm this as I don't currently have access to a Mac.

It doesn't seem that there are any superb tutorials for VST in general.